# How to terminate System Idle Process?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cpu-usage

Every time i start my windows 7, the CPU gets very high, up to 60% and i haven't opened nothing yet.

I opened task manager and saw what process where using the most. In the CPU usage and i found that **System Idle Process** had 67% of CPU usage.

After that i tried to kill that process but it showed me this.

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: are u the admin user?could u brief which process u were trying to kill?havent u tried kill command what happens while trying to do it?

Comment: the process I am trying to kill is **System Idle Process** @BlueBerry-vignesh4303

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How do I terminate System Idle Process?

You cannot kill the `System Idle` process. The real question is why would you want to?

`System Idle` is the process that runs when the computer has absolutely nothing better to do (in other words it is waiting for some other process to need more CPU resources).

---

#### What is the System Idle Process and why is it using most of the CPU?

> I mean, really, a process that regularly takes up 99% of your CPU’s
> time must be a bad thing, right?
>
> Nope, not at all. Just the opposite, in this case.
>
> ...
>
> The fact is that most computers can never really do nothing. When the
> computer is on, the CPU’s running and it must do something – even if
> that “something” is waiting for something real to do.
>
> Think of it as your computer just twiddling its virtual thumbs,
> waiting for something more important to do. The computer’s doing
> something (virtual thumb twiddling), but we wouldn’t call that doing
> anything useful.
>
> That’s called being idle.
>
> And the “System Idle Process” is the software that runs when the
> computer has absolutely nothing better to do.
>
> It effectively runs at the lowest possible priority so that if
> anything, anything at all, comes along for the CPU to work on, it can.
> When there’s nothing left to do, back to idle it goes.
>
> So having the System Idle Process using 90% of your CPU is a good
> thing … it means that that 90% is readily availble should there be any
> real work to do.

Source [What is the System Idle Process and why is it using most of the CPU?](https://askleo.com/what_is_the_system_idle_process_and_why_is_it_using_most_of_the_cpu/)

Comment: But my computer becomes too hot and that's so bad. How can i slow down CPU usage?

Comment: Thanks fo the answer but it doesn't help me.

Comment: @MChaker Really? It explains why it is impossible to do what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Ok i'll accept it for you.

Comment: I feel that this is a somewhat inappropriate simplification. The Idle process does not use the CPU at all! When there’s nothing to do, the CPU does nothing. It most certainly doesn’t perform busy waiting, wasting precious energy.

Comment: Why bother spamming the comments with Wikipedia quotes? Either include it in your answer, or don’t. There’s no need to run `HLT` in a loop because it stops the CPU completely until interrupted. “Twiddling thumbs” is busy waiting. It’s not what anyone uses.

Comment: If you think “sending `HLT`” (AKA turning it off) qualifies as using it. Other than some vague assertions around the internet I haven’t found anything but the obvious: When there’s nothing to do, the CPU is put to sleep by issuing the `HLT` command.