# Windows 7 - Quickheal's EMLPROXY.EXE taking up too much CPU, not killable afterwards

Tags: cpu, process, task-manager, tasks

Above mentioned EMLPROXY.EXE (from Quickheal Total Security) suddenly takes up 95% CPU, it is not killable from task manager and Resource Monitor. I get a "Permission denied" error.

I downloaded ProcessHacker (http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/index.php), and while it is able to (partially) terminate the selected process, it leaves behind a System Idle Process (PID 0) which still shows that 95% CPU consumption, however the actual resource usage drops to normal.

I tried to read this, but didn't understand much: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes/

What is the reason for such unkillable process? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate System Idle Process?](http://superuser.com/questions/934106/how-to-terminate-system-idle-process)

Comment: @DavidPostill: No, my problem is not that a system idle entry is present, my problem is that Task Manager and Resource Monitor CANNOT kill a process while some other 3rd party tool, partially can. Why so?

Comment: Because they are different programs and so have different capabilities.

Comment: @DavidPostill: That's interesting. I believe that Task Manager and Resource Monitor being provided by Windows, should have kernel privileges, which a 3rd party tool cannot have. It should only execute in user-level privileges. But my case seems to be the opposite.

Comment: User mode programs can have threads that enter kernel mode as the result of a call to a Windows API function, or because of an external event: when a device driver needs to process an interrupt or DPC, the code runs in the context of whichever thread happens to be active at the time.